# When sending a ship to mars what is the optimal travel path

Tags: mars, design, engineering, earth, calculation

its pretty self explanitory but I need to figure it out but not something from the past a ship that could be sent in the next 5-7 years what would be my time frame using the least amount of fuel and resources in a diagram form.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hohmann transfers are not used to send a ship to Mars.

Comment: Optimizing for propellant consumption and nothing else would give you a convoluted trajectory with multiple flyby maneuvers that takes many times longer to get there than any reasonable trajectory. Note that even direct trajectories are generally something less efficient...if you design to just barely get there with the most efficient trajectory, your mission fails if you're even a tiny bit overweight or a little bit late in launching. Also, humans are a lot lighter than cargo...something like Starship that can take either will have a lot of extra propellant when carrying people.

Comment: Also, is your destination the surface of Mars? Mars orbit? A flyby? Entering orbit will take a substantial amount of propellant, a lander can use a much lighter heat shield and aerodynamic braking. A flyby mission of course doesn't need anything more.